# Unchecked exception when using static imports, how come?

Tags: java, static-methods, unchecked-exception

I'm experiencing some strange behavior when using static imports of inherited static methods:

com/example/util/BaseUtil.java:

```
package com.example.util;

/*default*/ class BaseUtil {
    public static final void foo(){ System.out.println("foo"); }
}
```

com/example/util/Util.java:

```
package com.example.util;

public final class Util extends BaseUtil{
    public static void bar(){ System.out.println("bar"); }
    //foo() will be inherited
}
```

com/example/UtilTest.java

```
package com.example;

import static com.example.util.Util.bar;
import static com.example.util.Util.foo;

public class UtilTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bar();
        foo();
    }
}
```

Running `UtilTest` result in an unchecked exception!

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.example.util.BaseUtil from class com.example.UtilTest
>
> ```
>     at com.example.UtilTest.main(UtilTest.java:15)
> ```

However, if I were to reference the methods via `Util` (without static imports) everything works as expected:

com/example/UtilTest.java

```
package com.example;

import com.example.util.Util;

public class UtilTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Util.bar();
        Util.foo();
    }
}
```

So, what gives?

Comment: thanks, i learnt something new today, i dint know that static and final methods are accessible from your subclass. i knew they cant be inherited but dint know that the subclass can access them .. thanks again :)

Comment: final methods do get inherited, however, subclasses can't **override** them. on the other hand, methods with a `private` modifier in the parent class are not accessible to the subclasses (regardless of whether they're final or not)

Comment: i am confused now, FROM SCJP book by kathy and bert --- `Final methods cannot be overriden, only inherited methods may be overriden`

Comment: i don't know that book. but the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3) makes it pretty clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/*default*/ class BaseUtil { //only visible within the package com/example/util
```

That class has defualt access specifier, which makes it invisible from outside of that package.

You need to make it public.

**Update**

Following is how the decompilation looks like:

```
public class com.example.UtilTest extends java.lang.Object{
public com.example.UtilTest();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   invokestatic    #16; //Method com/example/util/Util.bar:()V
   3:   invokestatic    #21; //Method com/example/util/BaseUtil.foo:()V
   6:   return

}
```

And the following is what I get by using JD GUI

```
package com.example;

import com.example.util.BaseUtil;
import com.example.util.Util;

public class UtilTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Util.bar();
    BaseUtil.foo();
  }
}
```

which of course is not going to compile.

Looks like a hole in the compiler (may be due to the static imports) here.

Comment: Which proves that there is no real static inheritance? It's just making it easier to type?

Comment: True. The idea of inheritance only applies in case of objects (instances) not classes.

Comment: The question is: why can you can compile the version with `import static com.example.util.Util.foo;`?

Comment: @Shyj because `Util.foo` isn't accesible outside the `com.example.util` package.

Comment: @BheshGurung: what do you mean I "need to make it public"? i know what i can do in order to **force it to work** but it doesn't answer my question... also, whether you call it inheritance or hiding, in this particular example the result is the same. If I have a static method on a base class and the sub class has a static method with the same signature it overrides it. If the subclass doesn't have a static method with a matching signature, the method from the parent is "inherited"

Comment: Looks like it's a problem with the static import.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What do you mean? I asked why can you compile a code in whcih you appearently call a method which is not accessible (and the knowledge about that is available to the compiler).

Comment: @Andrey: This looks like a bug, not 100% sure though.

Comment: @Andrey The reason is that there is no real static inheritance, it's just making code easier to type, as you can see from the decompilation. Could the compiler have caught this? Yes. Does it really matter? Do you really want to write code that relies on static inheritance when java doesn't provide that capability (as in having a static inherited method by dynamically dispatched based on the subclass implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the answer, but something else to consider when importing static functions.

When you are working with static functions/constants, they can sometimes get compiled in-line. This depends on which compiler you are using. I can't remember off the top of my head which ones.

This is a problem when you import the static variable/function from an external library, then upgrade that library at runtime, your code will still have the OLD static function in it.

My suggestion is to avoid static functions altogether, and instead use a singleton object.
Use a framework such as spring to inject the singleton into your class at runtime.

It's good practice to make this object final, and use the constructor to set it.

This also makes testing easier as you can mock the singleton.

Comment: i like the idea of making it a singleton! to take it a step further, i would use an enum to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The first version of your code compiles effectively to

```
package com.example;

public class UtilTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        com.example.util.Util.bar();
        com.example.util.BaseUtil.foo();
    }
}
```

and since `BaseUtil` has package scope you can't call it from a different package and you get an exception.

The second version of your code compiles effectively to

```
package com.example;

public class UtilTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        com.example.util.Util.bar();
        com.example.util.Util.foo();
    }
}
```

Since `Util` is a public class you get access to all the methods including `foo`, since `foo` is visible to Util.

What puzzles me is why any of versions compile correctly?

Comment: @BheshGurung I compiled it both with JDK7 and Eclipse compiler.

Comment: the 1st version shouldn't compile. another javac bug.

Comment: @BheshGurung: that's very interesting, what version of Java and which platform/OS are you using?

Comment: @Andrey: My bad. I thought ShyJ was talking about the first version in this answer. The first version in your OP of course compiles and fails at runtime. And that was my misunderstanding at first.